# After changing Assembly(File)Version from 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0, settings get saved to a new folder, but loaded from the old one

Tags: c#, settings, .net-assembly

So after much time trying online solutions and asking collegues, I finally found the reason my Settings.settings wouldn't safe the settings I configured in my program:

When I changed `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` in `AssemblyInfo.cs` from 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0 (because it's the seconds Version of the program - I rewrote it in MVVM from an old version made years ago), it created a new folder to save the settings to - ...\AppData\local\MyProgram\MyProgram-{UID}\2.0.0.0.

The Problem is, it still loads the settings from the \1.0.0.0 folder.

How can I make it fully commit to being 2.0.0.0? Will this take long psychological sessions with my program, or can I just be straight forward somehow? I would really like my program to finally grow up to be a 2.0.0.0.

Edit: More info

AssemblyInfo.cs last lines now:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
```

After the upgrade, the second folder gets created and settings get saved to its user.settings, but still et loaded (Settings.Upgrade()) from the 1.0.0.0/user.settings.

[image: Folders after AssemblyVersion upgrade]

Comment: I am no able to reproduce your problem. VS2015 --> New Project --> Save a setting and reload it is working. After changing the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion the setting is back at its default value. It works like expected.

Comment: Here's my version: VS2015 -> Save settings -> loading works; have custom settings stored.
-> Upgrade assemblyversion to 2.0.0.0 -> start up -> loads stored settings -> change setting -> close + save setting -> resart -> loads setting from 1.0.0.0 again.

Comment: Also, "Fruchtzwerg" has to be the perfect fit to help my program grow! :D

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg: Got my answer below, wrong use of Settings.Upgrade() because I thought that's the normal method used to load settings from disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Settings.Upgrade()` only once when you start the new version application otherwise you are continuously overwriting the settings from the old version.

You should add a flag in your `user.config` that you set when you call `Upgrade()`.

Comment: Sooooo do I understand this right, now: Upgrade() doesn't actually load the settings, but gets the settings from an older version (like 1.0.0.0) and imports them to the newer version (like 2.0.0.0)? 

Do I have to do anything for the settings to load at the start of the appplication?

Comment: Yes, Upgrade() loads the old settings and imports.
No, they should load automatically. However, you will need to call Settings.Save() so that the new user.config file updates on disk.